# Destructuring exported object in import statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

If I have a module that does `export default { a: fn1, b: fn2 }`, is there a way to import only fn1, like `import { fn1 } from ...`?

Comment: `export { fn1, fn2 }`

Comment: don't use `default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `export { fn1, fn2 }` will fix what you are searching for, there various ways to export and import. Some of them are listed below.

One of the nice articles I have come across [**ES6 Modules in Depth**](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth)

**NAME EXPORTS**

```
export fn1;
export fn2;
// OR
export { fn1, fn2 };

import { fn1, fn2 } from '';
fn1();
// OR
import { fn1 as a, fn2 as b } from '';
a();
// OR
import * as funcs from '';
funcs.fn1();
```

**DEFAULT EXPORTS**

```
// ONLY ONE PER MODULE
export default fn1;

import fn1 from '';
fn1();
```

**MIXED**

```
export default fn2;

export fn1;

import fn2, { fn1 } from '';
import { default as fn2, fn1 } from ''; 
fn1();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to export them differently.

Instead of exporting a default object, export the values themselves:

```
export { fn1, fn2 };
```

Then, when you import, import with curly brackets and use the same exact name they were exported with:

```
import { fn1, fn2 } from './mymodule.js';
```

Then they'll be individual values you can use:

```
fn1();
```

It's not technically destructuring, but looks very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **default** 
use

```
export { fn1, fn2 }
```